# Use apply functions to avoid for loop, R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply, sapply

I want to optimize the following code by using one of the apply functions instead of a for loop but in vain :

```r
A=matrix(c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0),nrow=6,ncol=2)
corr=c()
for(i in 1:nrow(A))
{
  for(j in 0:(nrow(A)-i))
  {
    if(A[i,1]!=A[i+j,1] & A[i,2]!=A[i+j,2])
      corr=append(corr,"2 diff")
    else if(A[i,1]!=A[i+j,1] & A[i,2]==A[i+j,2])
      corr=append(corr,"diff gauche")
    else if(A[i,1]==A[i+j,1] & A[i,2]!=A[i+j,2])
      corr=append(corr,"diff droite")
    else
      corr=append(corr,1)
  }
}

B=matrix(nrow=NROW(A),ncol=NROW(A))
B[lower.tri(B, diag=T)]=corr 
B=t(B)
```

I've tried sapply but did not get the result, I may have misused the sapply function.

Comment: Please show your sapply attempt. Then we can help you see what went wrong.

Comment: If you want to use `apply` family just for speed up. Usually, it is not efficient.

Comment: Yes, the purpose behind using apply family is to speed up the running of the code.